# Html: Centering two div vertically and align one of them in the left side and the other one in the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap to style my html page. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Both word are at the top of the screen but I'd like for them to be in middle vertically. Also they  are in the center horizontally and I need them to be on the left and the right side of the screen.

Something like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">        
            <div class="col align-self-start">
                Hello
            </div>
            <div class="col align-self-end">
                World
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
</html>
```

I've tried different approach but very little change no metter how I edit my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - the script must be inside the body

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean align the text? somewhat unclear on the question if you mean the text to the entire "block" of the column.

```css
.container *,.container-fluid *  {
  border: solid 1px pink;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.test-high{height: 14rem;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container ">
  <div class="row align-items-center test-high">
    <div class="col text-left">
      Hello
    </div>
    <div class="col text-right">
      World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>A ml-auto example for the entire div removed the col class</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row test-high align-items-center ">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div class="ml-auto">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>A col example for the entire div as a column - note content may get outside its container col-1 and need say col-2 etc. ml-auto does the fun alignment</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row test-high align-items-center ">
    <div class="col-1">Hello</div>
    <div class="ml-auto col-1">World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a second example if you meant the entire bock/div

Comment: Added a third example with container-fluid and notes on col size/content

Comment: The third example works great to set the image on the side of the screen and was what I needed! The only problem is that the images are still on the top area of the screen and not centered vertically

Comment: Try adding the `align-middle` class to the row - not easy to reproduce with the sample; would probably have to make the container forced to larger (which may reduce the value of the container class perhaps) Ref https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/

Comment: I tested this with some forced height and then added the `align-items-center` class to do that vertical  for this example and added that.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has classes for vertical alignment. You’d want `align-middle` - [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/)

Answer (score -1):

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background:#c9edff;
}
body {
margin: 0;
background: teal;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'roboto';
}
.align-self-start {
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
transform: translateY(-50%); 
padding-left: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0%;
background: whitesmoke;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;

}
.align-self-start li {
padding-left: 10px;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.align-self-end {
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
transform: translateY(-50%); 
padding-right: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
right: 0%;
background: darkgreen;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;
}
.align-self-end li {
padding-right: 10px;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 10px;
}
.align-self-end a {
color: yellow;
margin: auto;
}
.nav_bar {
width: 100%;
background: lightblue;
display: inline-flex;
}
.nav_bar li {
margin: auto;
list-style: none;
}
.nav_bar a {
color: black;
}
a {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}
.border_form {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.border_form input{
height: 40px;
width: 400px;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px whitesmoke;
}
.border_form input:focus{
height: 40px;
width: 400px;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px whitesmoke;
outline: none;
}
.border_form button {
height: 40px;
width: 400px;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px whitesmoke;
outline: none;
}
footer  {
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;
  background-color: yellow; 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
footer li { 
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
    }
  footer a { 
padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="nav_bar">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">News</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
<div class="border_form">
<form>
<input type="text" class="username_css" placeholder="Username">
<br>
<br>
<input type="password" class="password_css" placeholder="Password">
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">       
            <div class="col align-self-start">
              <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Hello 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Hello 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hello 3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Hello 4</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col align-self-end">
              <ul>
             <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">World 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">World 3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">World 4</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Footer</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Footer 2</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Footer 3</a></li>
                </ul>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

// for all 1080p screens
Its been updated. This method will work on any browser. If it is not working on any other browser..  Then you need to use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
.your_div {

}
}
// for iphone se
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px)  {
.your_div {

}

}
```

^^
and you need to add

Comment: still invalid - an `li` must be nested into a parent `ul` OR `ol` - your browser MAY work but that is on the browser developer trying to handle poorly written HTML ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: And yet you’re posting invalid html, which serves no useful purpose.

Comment: I am totally, sorry!  I never checked my html syntax, it is all checked now. Please forgive me! Hope this edit, works.